# Installing software the first time a system boots after CentOS installation

Tags: software-installation, startup, centos, rc

I have a custom text based CentOS 6.4 installation that installs the OS, then after the first boot I have a custom `rc.local` file that installs custom applications and prepares the system for our customers.  When this install completes, the original `rc.local` that came with the OS is copied back into place for normal operation.

This has worked fine for years but would like to know if there is a better way to install software after the first boot? OR ... Is this the best way to install additional applications after the OS is installed?

Answer (score 2):

These days automated provision and configuration management (which includes installed software) has evolved greatly.

To provision a CentOS machine I would typically:

- register a new system in [`cobbler`](http://www.cobblerd.org/)
- create a A/AAA DNS entry, a host entry and a [`puppet`](http://puppetlabs.com/) service entry for this host in [`FreeeIPA`](http://www.freeipa.org/)
- PXE boot the machine (virtual or physical, the method applies)
- Sit back and relax.

For this to work, though, I have previously:

- created a [`kickstart`](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart) file/template in `cobbler` for this system, or profile of systems.
- ensured that a local mirror exists for all the repositories I'm going to need (not mandatory, but very helpful)
- defined all the configuration that applies to this host in the `puppetmaster`
- defined all the information related to `sudo` rules, HBAC, `ssh` key management, SELinux user mappings, etc in the Identity Manager.

This infrastructure provides centralized services, and a reproducible, (almost) unattended way of installing a machine.

If your `puppet` code is optimized, you will end up with a system containing all the software you consider necessary for a host *before* the first boot.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'll take a look at cobbler.  Not sure if it will work because my distribution needs to be on a CD/DVD.  Some of our systems are setup standalone with no DNS.  Only accessible by IP.